# Catch a type error in C++

Tags: c++, types, try-catch, typeerror

How do i check if a result is of the right type(int, float, double, etc.) and then throw and catch an exception in case it's not?

Thanks all,

Vlad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you give more detail about what is giving you "a result" you may be able to determine what you need from there and more likely in a better way.

If all you really want is to check the type, use [`typeid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid).
More info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)

Following Daniel's model of editing posts to actually answer the question after stating something else...

From my other comment:

> You have to do this BEFORE you have
>   just the result. Checking for overflow
>   after is not a good idea. Do a check
>   on the numbers before adding to see if
>   they will overflow, or restrict input
>   to be less than half the max value of
>   the type

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to know that at runtime with C++. These would be compile-time errors.

To answer your second question, you have to manually check for buffer overflows/underflows or use a more appropriate datatype.

Comment: +1, but it's exactly the opposite - there's almost no way *not* to know that at runtime, because otherwise code wouldn't compile ;-)

Comment: Except when using a template instance, where the template parameter can be any class/type at all, even one that didn't exist when the template was written.

Comment: But templates are not at runtime. They are generated at compile-time too.

Comment: It all depends on what he is getting this result from.  If it is a pointer to something cast as a void* that he is getting from somewhere else you would not know it's true type unless you were told.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll get is [dynamic_cast](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc05keyword_dynamic_cast.htm).

Comment: dynamic_cast doesn't work for built-in types. It works only for references/pointers to polymorphic types.

Comment: Which is why I said the *closest* you'll get is dynamic_cast (not "the answer is dynamic_cast", note the difference). I mentioned dynamic_cast because I wasn't sure if the OP was asking for *just* builtins or for a larger set of types.